# Is it possible for ancient undiscovered islands to exists on earth?

Tags: identify-this, islands

Have human explored and mapped all the islands on earth and Is it possible for undiscovered Islands to exists on earth?

I am more interested to know only about stable old Islands and not newly created islands from natural phenomenon.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cartography and possibly geology, but not travel.

Comment: After the alteration to the question to be more specifically interested in old ones, yeah, it's becoming more geography and not travel as defined in the [help]. Voting to close too.

Comment: If you know of people claiming that such islands exist, I recommend trying the Skeptics site.

Comment: @DJClayworth can you please migrate this question there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old undiscovered islands is possible, but unlikely, given we have satellite imagery of the earth down to very high resolution detail.

However, there are plenty of examples of mistakes being made, and some islands that we 'know about' may not even exist. As recently as 2012, [an island was found not to exist](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/australiaandthepacific/9718177/Missing-Pacific-island-riddle-solved.html) despite being on historical maps for 150 years, and even on Google Maps!

Then, volcanoes are creating new islands every so often with eruptions.  Just a few months ago, a [new one was created in the Pacific Ocean, south of Japan](http://www.wired.com/2013/11/pacific-eruption-at-nishino-shima-producing-new-island/).  This is fairly common for smaller ones to be made, but they don't often last long, so this was special. But given that scientist monitor eruptions and study them, it's pretty common to discover the new formations rather quickly.

Similarly a few years ago, a [giant pumice island was formed](http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/news/2012/08/giant-pumice-island-floats-in-the-pacific/) (although technically more of a 'raft' of pumice) after some eruptions and earthquakes.

So, short answer - it's possible, but unlikely for old ones to exist, and while new ones are created occasionally, we usually find them pretty fast.  Of course, this doesn't mean we've explored them, just photographed/mapped them.

Comment: do ancient unexplored Islands exist or all such **old** Islands have been discovered?

Comment: @travel101 you've actually altered the question now, which is frustrating, as it's making it clear that it may be off-topic.  However, in this case I refer to you my first paragraph - it's possible, but unlikely.  How could we possibly answer 'yes' - because if we know about them, they'd be discovered already. But we have mapped the entire world, so yes, there's a record of them.  However unexplored is a different meaning to discovered - and there are certainly tiny islands that people have seen but not bothered to actually visit.